# Remove all markers on Google Map?

Tags: google-maps

I have an array of marker `markersOnMap[];`
And I sets the map on all markers in the array by

```
.//..some code...
  for (var i = 0; i < markersOnMap.length; i++) {
        htmlMarker = new HTMLMarker(markersOnMap[i].x, markersOnMap[i].y);

        htmlMarker.setMap(gmap);
    }
```

How can I remove all maker?

Comment: See the example in the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create an array of the html markers and keep pushing markers that you are adding to the map into the array as well. .

```
//..some code...
var htmlMarkerArray = new Array();  
for (var i = 0; i < markersOnMap.length; i++) {
    htmlMarker = new HTMLMarker(markersOnMap[i].x, markersOnMap[i].y);

    htmlMarker.setMap(gmap);
    htmlMarkerArray.push(htmlMarker); 
}
```

To delete the markers you need to iterate through the html marker array and remove the markers using the `setMap(null)` method. You can use the delete function as shown below :

```
function deleteMarkers(){
    for (var i = 0; i < markersOnMap.length; i++) {
        htmlMarkerArray[i].setMap(null);
    }
}
```